# Is there any way to maximize an InfoWindow in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

The old (v2) version of Google Maps API allowed infowindows to be maximized (see [this example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/megawindow/maxcontent_ajax.html)) but I can't find any equivalent feature in v3.
The same happens with tabbed infowindows too (they aren't supported anymore).

Is there any way to do that (even with a plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the documentation, it looks like there's no way to perform maximization on InfoWindow.